# How to create a search engine with highlighting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I want to create a search engine, in Rails, for my website, with an overview (some words around the searched word) and the word highlighted. Something like google or github.

Is it a gem for this? What's is the best way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: What searching have you done so far?

Comment: For the moment I have a simple Article.where("like ?", "%#{word}%") and a standard index page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are varios search engines like sphinx or solr that also have gems to connect rails to it eg. which are gems on its own. There are railscasts for both of them.

When you want to highlight the results you can use a combination of the `excerpt` and `highlight` methods provided by Rails:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html